# how to select a submatrix from a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

I have a large complex matrix **A** of size **500 * 600**, but i need to use only a small submatrix from the **matrix A.**

is there anyway to do that in Matlab 2013R by selecting the start and end range of the rows and columns?

Comment: To complete the answer in the duplicate question, if you want to select a submatrix with successive elements from a certain axis, you can use the [colon  operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (`:`). For example `B = A(100:200, 50:60)`;

Comment: Thank you very much.. that's exactly what i wanted